# IdentityServer4 + Asp Identity + EF Configure two UsersSet/Providers

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4, identity

Having trouble finding a good lead on this. I have a aspnetcore app with identityserver4 configured to use asp identity with a sql database.

There is a business requirement that all non AD users are stored in this asp identity database.
All AD users are defined on Azure. I can authenticate them with LDAP and receive their data.
The issue comes after authentication. Whenever asp identity tries to call:

```cs
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
```

With an AD user, it fails because the user does not exist. This is because it is using EF to query the asp identity database, where those users are not defined.

```cs
private DbSet<TUser> UsersSet { get { return Context.Set<TUser>(); } }
```

I can not store any of the AD information in the asp identity database (business requirement). I am trying to find a way to get the user store to look both at the asp identity tables, as well as Azure (via LDAP).

My current method for getting the AD users when doing initial auth is here:

```cs
await GetADUser(queryParams),
```

It uses LDAP to authenticate and grab the user object.

One additional requirement is that I can not use an external login screen, the login must all be done from the same company facing login UI. AKA no external providers.

Comment: Abstract your UserManager out, then make the call to both sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @mxmissile, abstracting the UserManager out was the correct call. Then you can also abstract out other managers as needed for special functionality. This is in fact the only class in the inheritance layer for this part of the code that is virtual.

There are built in functions that let you register your custom managers:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager<IdentityUser>>()
            .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager<IdentityUser>>()
```

Hopefully this is a little help to any others that have a similar question. I ended up just overriding a couple of the functions from the base user manager and just calling the base method for anything that did not need my new logic. By default it looks like ASP Identity does not try to look up users by email - just fyi.